# In Perl, on what basis should one choose between passing a reference to a hash/array and passing a hashref/arrayref scalar?

Tags: perl, coding-style

To be brief, I'm wondering if there are any best-practice reasons for deciding between:

```
my %hash = ( foo => 1, bar => 2 );
# some in-between logic
some_func(\%hash);
```

and

```
my $hashref = { foo => 1, bar => 2 };
# some in-between logic
some_func($hashref);
```

Or is purely a style decision?

Comment: First of all, there's no such thing as a reference to a list.  There are arrayrefs and hashrefs.  An arrayref would be the closest thing to a reference to a list, but what you've actually constructed there with `{}` is a hashref.  An arrayref would use `[]`.

Comment: @cjm: From perlref: "Taking a *reference to an enumerated list* is not the same as using square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of references!"

Comment: 1.`print \%list` 2.`print $listref` 3.look for difference

Comment: @BipedalShark: That quote does not apply here.  It's talking about code like `\($x, $y, $z)`.  The code applies the reference-operator to a list construct.  The point is that it creates a list of references, not a reference to array; it's equivalent to `(\$x, \$y, \$z)`.

Comment: @BipedalShark => that refers to the behavior of the `\(1, 2, 3)` construct, which is equivalent to `(\1, \2, \3)` and has nothing to do with taking a reference to a list, which is not possible in perl.  Square brackets are the anonymous array constructor `[1, 2, 3] === do {my @x = (1, 2, 3); \@x}`

Comment: Well, okay, but the term is used everywhere in perldoc to refer to a referenced array or hash. To say "there's no such thing as a reference to a list" is pure silliness.

Comment: @BipedalShark, I can't find one instance of Perl's documentation talking about a "reference to a list" or a "listref".  Can you point out one?  (Other than the one you mentioned, which is saying that applying the reference operator to a list _does not_ make a list reference, but rather a list of references.)

Comment: `perldoc -X CGI`: "The optional third argument (-default) can be either a reference to a list containing the values to be selected by default, or can be a single value to select."

Comment: @BipedalShark => `CGI` seems to use `reference to an array` and `reference to a list` interchangeably.  This is incorrect.  It is always a reference to an array.  While module documentation usually is a good source of information, some authors are lax with terminology, and it's not surprising that there are a few inaccuracies in the docs of a module as large and old as `CGI`.  When in doubt, always trust the documentation found here http://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html (And feel free to send in a bug report to `CGI` about the list/array discrepancy)

Comment: Question/sample code have been adjusted. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are equivalent and interchangeable.  The decision should be made based on what is clearest for you.

You can also move back and forth:

```
my $hashref = {x => 1, y => 2};

our %hash; *hash = $hashref;

some_func($hashref);
some_func(\%hash);    # \%hash == $hashref
```

In general I prefer to work with the plural forms `%name` and `@name` since it results in less line noise due to dereferencing.  That and `some_func(\%var)` is clearer with regard to `var`'s type than `some_func($var)`

Answer (score 1):

These two examples do exactly the same thing.  So it mainly depends on which is more convenient for what else, if anything, you do with the `%list` variable and/or `$listref` variable.

Or maybe you'd like to skip the extra variable entirely:

```
some_func( { foo => 1, bar => 2 } );
```

(Less likely now that you've added those "in-between logic" comments.)

Comment: +1 - agree, it's purely about convenience; however, it *should* be as consistent as practical throughout the program.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated above, they're the same though the first may give you better context to what type of variable (i.e. a hash) you're using in your "some in-between logic" code.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it won't make a difference, but I have had some nasty bugs that occurred from trying to change where my reference points if I pass in a reference-of list.

Unless I really want to change the contents of a pre-existing array or hash, I personally favor using anonymous lists/hashes (like your second example).

This is just personal experience, though. I will admit that maybe if I understood Perl better I would know the objective best practices (if any exist).